# Cloud Agent, Apache, and drupal's .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Installed Apache and Cloud Agent.
Agent collects information from mod_status. Everything is ok.

However, when I add drupal files (with .htaccess), Agent can't collect stat anymore.

I already tried many configuration and now I am super confused about VirtualHosts. I used standard agent's configuration for virtualhost:

```
ExtendedStatus on
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName local-stackdriver-agent.stackdriver.com
<Location /mod_status>
  SetHandler server-status
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

In http.conf I changed only DocumentRoot.

Can someone please explain me why the requests go to drupal's folder, and not to local-stackdriver-agent.stackdriver.com VirtualHost?